# I have written this code for fetch record from my table name is owners... but some error is occurs... is there something missing?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystationary", "root", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String qry;
    qry = "select * from owners where usernm='" + jTextField1.getText() + "',password='" + jTextField2.getText() + "'";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
    while (rs.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome '" + jTextField1.getText() + "' !");

    }

} catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: Rather than posting "but some error occurs", why not edit your post and **tell** us what the error is and any pertinent background information too. Put just a little more effort into your question and you'll help get a decent answer.

Comment: "Some error"? Not helpful :(

Comment: error is http://prntscr.com/f15k8c

Comment: Try generating legal SQL. Then fix your SQL to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Please post the error text directly in your question.

Comment: is there any syntax error in my sql query ?

Comment: Yes. That's actually why you're getting an error stating there's an SQL syntax error in your query. And it's pretty basic.

Comment: if any error is there then red curly line should be generate but in my code no any red line generated....

Comment: @Jay The IDE will highlight *Java* errors, not SQL-embedded-in-concatenated-strings errors. The error message you're getting is explicit, and correct.

Comment: Why do you believe `where usernm='X',password='Y'` is valid SQL syntax? Looks like you need to (re)read the SQL guide on how to build a simple SQL statement. *Hint: The `,` doesn't belong.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PreparedStatement instead to avoid any syntax error or SQL Injection:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
        "select * from owners where usernm = ? and password = ?")) {

    ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
    ps.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(qry);

    if (rs.next()) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome '" + jTextField1.getText() + "' !");
    }
}
```

Your real problem is with the `,` when you want to use where you have to use `and` not `,`

```
qry = "select * from owners where usernm='"+jTextField1.getText()+"', password='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
//------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Instead you have to use :

```
qry = "select * from owners where usernm='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' and password='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

But PreparedStatement is more secure.

---

Another thing, if you want to check for one use, then you can use `if (rs.next())` instead of `while (rs.next())`

Comment: Thanks. I will use your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
 qry = "select * from owners where usernm='"+jTextField1.getText()+"',password='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
```

You are using a comma to separate your conditions when you should be using the SQL operator "AND."

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM owners WHERE usernm='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' AND password='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
```

Also, as Dave Newton pointed out, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. And your while loop after the executeQuery() call doesn't actually use your result set.